# Make Custom Navigation drawer like You-Tube in android

Tags: android, youtube, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

Hello friends i wnat to make custom slidng drawer like you-tube in my application

[image]

When user click on any item it should be show me like above image which i highlight so any idea how can i achieve this ?

Comment: its called the navigation drawer.

Comment: go through following link for navigation Drawer's UI principals:
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

and then go through thi link to create actual navigation drawer
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: check this http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/slide-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android.html @Harshal Kalavadiya

Comment: @ Jigar Jariwala , @ Indiandroid : i already seen that exapmles in but this examples highlight selector in whole listbackground but i also want  red color indicator at starting which is mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesterday I faced same problem

`but this examples highlight selector in whole listbackground but i also want red color indicator at starting which is mention`

You need to create two selector. 1. For whole item 2. for that red part

For that Place a view in listitem on left side and create a selector for it.

then use following code. Here `android:duplicateParentState="true"` works for you.
When this attribute is set to true, the view gets its drawable state 
 (focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from 
 itself.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_for_red" />
```